# Does Java have a built-in way to add an element to an alphabetical List?

Tags: java

Is there a method already provided in the Java 5 library to add an element to an alphabetical `List`?

In other words, say I have a `List<String>` with three elements `{"apple","cat","tree"}` and I want to add the `String` "banana" while keeping the `List` in alphabetical order; is there an easy way to simply add it to the `List`, so that the `List` now has four elements `{"apple","banana","cat","tree"}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`PriorityQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).  These are sorted according to the comparator of the objects they hold.  `Strings` are, by default, sorted according to the ASCII values of the first differing character, which will give the results you want (as long as the capitalization of all the words is all the same.)

Quick example:

```
PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>();
pq.add("banana");
pq.add("apple");
pq.add("orange");
pq.poll(); // Returns "apple"
pq.poll(); // Returns "banana"
pq.poll(); // Returns "orange"
```

Note that the Big-O runtime of both `add()` and `poll()` is `O(logn)`.

Edit: `PriorityQueue` is best if you want to remove the items in order, but you will need a [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) to *iterate* over the collection in order.

Comment: And it's very easy to write a Comparator<String> class to compare Strings without regard to case.

Comment: The original poster asked for a `List`, which the `PriorityQueue` does not implement.

Comment: I didn't think the OP was referring to the actual Java `List` interface.  Maybe the OP could clarify for us.

Comment: A PriorityQueue is just the thing I needed. I was only using a List because it's all I knew; I forgot all the different data structures available. Thanks!

Comment: `NavigableSet` would be more conventional.

Answer (score 5):

there is SortedSet and SortedMap. However both cant support duplicates. if this is what you need then use the Set data structure. You your return type need to be List then he use Collections.list(set) to conver the final Set to the List. javadoc here http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list(java.util.Enumeration)

Comment: As documented in the Java API, a `Set` can never be a `List`.

Comment: well that is true as it cant have duplicates...but i left it for @Ricket to decide as he might just want this. if no dups required but the return type need to be List then he can use Collections.list()

Comment: This answer might be more useful if it linked to the appropriate documentation pages for these two, and if the above comment was actually included as part of the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do so that I know is to add the element, then use `Collections.sort()` on your List. `String`s will sort lexicographically. `Collections.sort()` works on any List containing elements that implement the Compare interface. If you want to sort a list of custom objects easily, make sure your T implements Comparable.

EDIT: Of course, as other posters have pointed out, there are better data structures for this. However, if you absolutely need a `List` this is the fast-n-dirty way.

Comment: Of course, this approach is `O(nlogn)` for each insertion, as opposed to `O(logn)` for the binary search insertion approach.

Comment: True. From a maintenance perspective, though, sometimes Collections.sort() is preferable, if you know the list will remain fairly short. That way in three years when the new guy looks at your code your intentions are fairly self-evident.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at TreeSet.
If you're adding strings only, then the default String.compareTo() is already implemented.

Otherwise, you can build a comparator to do the ordering for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are starting with an empty list and you add elements to it while keeping it in sorted order you would

1. find the insertion point by either linear search (if you use a linked list) or binary search if you use an array list
2. at the insertion point, say i, you would use list.add(i, element)

e.g.

```
String element = "banana";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
int i = Collections.binarySearch(list, element);
if (i < 0) {
    list.add(-(i+1), element);
} else {
    list.add(i, element);
}
```

ps. Collections.binarySearch() will degrade to a linear search when it is not randomly searchable.

Answer (score 1):

`List` is an unordered collection.  While you can sort after adding or properly index your adds, it's easier to use a collection that's built to maintain an order, like a `TreeSet`.  That will ensure ordering through changes to the set and will also ensure the set is balanced for fast access.

Comment: `List` is *not* an unordered collection, though it may be *unsorted*. That's a big difference. See the documentation on `List`, which says in the very first sentence that it is an *ordered* collection.

Comment: List maintains the insertion order where as set maintains the natural order

Comment: That's only true for a `TreeSet`. A `HashSet` on the other hand appears unordered and may even change the order completely just because of a single insertion or deletion.

Comment: Ordered means that you get things out in a certain order.  In the default case, you get things out in the order you put them in, which is an order, just not SORTED order.  Just like a list on paper, Lists run from top to bottom. Unordered would return values like a bingo machine, or grabbing items from a hat.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it yourself, you could binary search to find the location where each item would be added in alphabetical order and then add it to that position, which will keep the list in sorted order.
Edit: You might want to do this if you want all of the functionality of a `List` while still having it always sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The `addToSorted` function I wrote is not provided by default by Java, but is still very simple. The `Collections.binarySearch` function returns either a value `>= 0` if the element is found or a value `< 0` if the value is not found. In the latter case, it returns the insertion position (somewhat encoded so that it is always negative).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class BinSort {

  private static void addToSorted(List<String> list, String element) {
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, element);
    if (index < 0)
      list.add(-(index + 1), element);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.add("apple");
    words.add("cat");
    words.add("tree");
    addToSorted(words, "banana");
    System.out.println(words);
  }
}
```